# How much JavaScript code should be used in asp MVC?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to the asp MVC programming. Since you can use jQuery/JavaScript code in the View, it seems to me you even can rarely put c# code in the Model/controller. This means most of the business logic is done by jQuery only, and this makes the website looks like a pure JavaScript coded project. If this is true, what's the deal to use C# to code in MVC framework?

If you think c# is easy to be maintained and developed, then how much code should be developed in c# compared with JavaScript in MVC framework? And in what situations should we use c# code in Model/controller rather than JavaScript in View?

Besides, what's the advantages of using asp MVC to develop websites compare with pure jQuery/jQuery QI developed websites?

Comment: C# is processed server-side and javascript is processed client-side. This means that, for the most part, they achieve completely different things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery/JavaScript in the view will run client-side and will not have access to server-side resources (unless it uses AJAX to retrieve those).  C# code is server-side code.  One is not a substitute for the other - instead they're complementary to each other.

Business logic in client-side may not be prudent (depends on your application and requirements) because:

1. you may not want to expose your business logic to clientside as it can be viewed.
2. it may create significant security gap if exposed.
3. malicious client can manipulate clientside code and cause code to run with a different logic (some pricing attacks were done in that way in the past).
4. and a few other reasons.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is fast. That's the simple way of answering the advantages to that.

You shouldn't really put any C# code in the views, besides accessing the model and looping through to display results.

When you can, your business logic should work things out, and store them in view models.

Whatever is built in MVC really can be built in JavaScript. C# can give you access to some great libraries such as NewtonJson and LINQ (my favourite).

I use the C# primarily for accessing the database for which we use Entity Framework and performing what calculations where the results can be loaded in a view model.

MVC can quickly offer you ways to add authorisation to different areas of your website, roles etc.